# The problem with the grass

Tags: geometry-nodes

Every time I try to make a terrain that is not flat, the grass passes through it. Can anyone explain me how to fix it?
[image]

---

When I add an object to geometry nots it is always rotated like in the photo, so I have to reposition it vertically, that is also another problem. the grass is vertical, but when I add it to the geometry, it always faces the other direction.

[image]

[image]

---

I only use subdivide

[image]
.......................

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be solved by:

1. Appling scale and rotation, location, etc.
2. Did you apply the displace modifier if you are using it? You have to apply it.

Comment: Is the problem solved?